# Where can I learn how to make a C++ program interact with the Operating System (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system

I am a C++ beginner.

I'd like to create small programs that interact with the operating system (using Kubuntu Linux). So far, I have not been able to locate any tutorial or handbook to get C++ to interface with the OS.

In PHP, I can use the command exec() or the backtick operator to launch commands typically executed in a console.
How can I do similar things in C++?
How can I get my C++ program to execute any other command?
How can I get the output of such commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`system()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) command in [`stdlib`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/) to execute system commands:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    system("ls -l");
}
```

`system()` returns an `int` as its return value, but the value of the int is system-dependent. If you try and use a command that doesn't exist, you'll get the standard "no such command" output back, and usually a non-zero return value. (For example, running `system("ls -l");` on my Windows XP machine here returns a value of 1.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code and the pointer to the proper library. That was very useful. +1

Comment: I had considered marking one of the answers as the 'correct' one. I was aware of the check mark. However, the three answers were helpful and each added additional information that the other two didn't have, so I was hesitating as to which one to choose. But if it helps the system, I'll go with your recommendation. It's a shame I can choose all three :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`system()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) to execute arbitrary commands but, if you want to easily control the input and output with the program, you should look into [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

For even *more* control, you can look into doing exactly what a shell might do, creating some extra file descriptors, forking to start another process, setting up file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 (input, output and error) in that process to connect them to your original process file descriptors then exec'ing the program you want to control. This isn't for the faint of heart :-)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning popen(). Now that I know what to search, I have been able to find more resources on the web (e.g. http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html ). I'd like to soon be able to try out the stuff that "isn't for the faint of heart" :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `system()` as instructed previously or you can use libraries which provide access to standard POSIX API. [unistd.h](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) and [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) include many functions for OS interaction. The possibilities with these libraries are endless as you can implement the functionalities yourself. A simple example: scan a directory for text files with `scandir()` and print the contents of the files.

Comment: Thank you for the additional pointers to other libraries. I'm starting with something very simple, and I've bookmarked those libs for when I need to expand further what I can do. +1