# Starting/Stoping an application parlally from Unix application

Tags: c++, unix, qprocess

I want to use [Qprocess](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qprocess) to start other applications from linux c++ application.

I want to start and stop another application from my application.

How to link Qprocess to my build. Which .so files are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QProcess` is not a native c++ class, it is part of the Qt framework http://qt-project.org/
If you are simply looking for a solution to start another application from yours, you could e.g. look into `system` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) which you should able to use easily (after including cstdlib of course).

If you need to get back the console output of your application `popen` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) might be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried system but there is no way to find pid to stop it. Also I looked into http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Process.html but its making the process zombie which starts application. I want to run both application simultaneously.

Comment: maybe http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/boost_process/tutorial.html could be a possible route?

Comment: so far i tired qprocess and poco. I will try popen and boost process.

Comment: this thread on this site might give you some more hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process

Comment: and this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329216/where-can-i-learn-how-to-make-a-c-program-interact-with-the-operating-system

Comment: thanks i will check and let you know popen and boost